# T-SQL. Процедура бесконечно долго исполняется, если в нее передается текстовый параметр

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется T-SQL код на базе SQL Server, который успешно выполняется за минуту:

```
DECLARE @period varchar(20)
SET @period = '2024.02'

SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.column = @period
```

И имеется тот же самый код но в виде процедуры, принимающей текстовый параметр:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeProcedure] @period varchar(7)
BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.column = @period

END
```

И пример вызова процедуры:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @per varchar(20)
SET @per = '2024.02'

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SomeProcedure] @per

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Данный вызов процедуры так и не удалось успешно завершить, так как он выполняется очень долгое время.

Что можно попробовать ещё, чтобы сократить время исполнения до ожидаемого?

Я пробовал захардкодить эту текстовую переменную в процедуре - она успешно исполнялась за ту же минуту, как и в обычном запросе.

Пробовал в обычном запросе создавать varchar(max) переменную вместо varchar(20), но он всё равно успешно завершался за приемлемое время.

Comment: А что если при вызове хранимки добавить `with recompile`?

Comment: @alexander-petrov, добавление `with recompile` в вызов процедуры никакого дополнительного эффекта не дал. Процедура всё также бесконечно долго выполняется.

Comment: Ну я бы попробовал при вызове передавать всё же в точности того же типа переменную, что и в процедуре `varchar(7)`, но скорее всего это никак не повлияет.

Comment: А покажите как описание таблицы. Например, `nullable` ли это поле, по которому условие ставится? Вообще почитайте вот это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440944/sql-server-query-fast-but-slow-from-procedure Там два основных решения: через присвоение параметра функции в локальную переменную и через `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`.

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) - хорошо известная статья, рекомендуемая к ознакомлению (есть перевод на русский).

Comment: Ага, по ссылке на en.so, которую привёл CrazyElf есть и ссылка на статью Соммарскога, и упомянуты все полезные методики, применяемые в таких случаях: recompile, введение дополнительных переменных. Разве что отключение parameter sniffing на уровне БД никто не описал. Пробуйте всё, что-нибудь да поможет. Полезные ссылки: [1](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/), [2](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2016-parameter-sniffing/), [3](https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/)

Comment: Как вызываете процедуру и как измеряете время выполнения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @CrazyElf за [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440944/sql-server-query-fast-but-slow-from-procedure).

Решил проблему изменением процедуры, добавив прослойку в виде дополнительной локальной переменной между передаваемым в процедуру аргументом и условием в `SELECT`-е:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeProcedure] @period varchar(7)
BEGIN

DECLARE @periodLocal varchar(20)  = @period;

SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.column = @periodLocal

END
```

Comment: Странно только, что у вас размер `varchar` везде разный )

Comment: @CrazyElf, да я уже боюсь что-либо в коде трогать. А то поменяю тип переменной, а потом 10 страниц мануалов читать, что так делать нежелательно, и вообще компилятор там вавилонские башни в плане запроса рисует. Работает - не трож.

Comment: Так то да, главное что работает. Но то, что в вызове процедуры, в параметрах процедуры и внутри процедуры вы используете `varchar` разного размера, это выглядит странновато. Хотя если размера хватает, то вероятно это ни на что не влияет.