# Как улучшить производительность вызова хранимой процедуры через Entity Framework в C# API?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, mvc

Имеется API написанное на C# с использованием Entity Framework в связке с SQL SERVER, так же на стороне SQL SERVER существует несколько процедур, которые я вызываю через Entity Framework из контроллера. Пример одного вызова процедуры:

```
var result = context.MyProcedure.FromSqlRaw(
"EXECUTE [MyDB].[dbo].[MyProcedure] @Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4",
    new SqlParameter("@Param1", param1),
    new SqlParameter("@Param2", param2),
    new SqlParameter("@Param3", param3)
    new SqlParameter("@Param4", param4 == "all" ? DBNull.Value : param4)
).ToList();


return Ok(new { result });
```

Ранее вызовы хранимых процедур выполнялись за ~2 секунды, но теперь они занимают ~20 секунд. В то же время, операции, такие как фильтрация данных, получение по ID и авторизация, выполняются быстро.

Проведя тест без использования Entity Framework в новом консольном приложении, я обнаружил, что процедура выполняется в пределах ожидаемых 2-3 секунд. Однако, замена вызова через Entity Framework на аналогичный код в MVC приводит к той же задержке в ~20 секунд. Кажется, что задержка связана с процессом извлечения данных после вызова процедуры.

Как можно улучшить производительность таких вызовов? Есть ли способы оптимизации или альтернативные методы вызова хранимых процедур через Entity Framework для уменьшения времени выполнения?

Comment: Хм, что-то знакомое. Вот на днях с процедурой случай был: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1570512/t-sql-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf Хотя может это не совсем то, но почитайте там ссылки приведённые, вдруг что-то поможет.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо за ссылку, надеялся что ситуация аналогична моей и я найду быстрое решение. Но ведь легких путей не бывает? К моему сожалению именно на стороне SQL SERVER всё работает быстро, как и в чистом консольном приложении C#. А вот под MVC net8 заставляет меня идти за чаем и размышлять о великом.

Comment: Жалко. А вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767803/entity-framework-query-slow-but-same-sql-in-sqlquery-is-fast Обычно всё-таки всё упирается в строки, либо в nullable. Вы бы всё-таки показали, что за таблица, что за процедура и код модели. И сколько в таблице данных примерно. А так это всё слишком абстрактно. И ещё попробуйте подсмотреть, в какой sql запрос это разворачивается и попробовать этот запрос непосредственно на сервере. Там как-то просто вроде в EF было запрос залогировать.

Comment: Модель довольно мала, всего один столбец типа "строка" и несколько типа "число", в самой модели указаны типы данных. В таблице, которую мне возвращает процедура не более 20-ти записей. Сама же процедура вызывает простой `SUM` по различным полям в зависимости от самого запроса. Но здесь дело даже не в самом вызове процедуры через Entity Framework, а в том, что процедура очень медленно работает именно в MVC, в простом консольном приложении с теми же вводными данными она возвращает данные моментально. А в MVC даже с простым `SqlQuery` приходится ждать

Comment: Может дело вообще не в запросе, а в том, что в MVC что-то неправильно работает? Странно, что у вас запрос не асинхронный.